# Coded Ui-Data driven tests

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am automating a test scenario which runs on different test inputs.The inputs are passed from a CSV file or MTM. During the test run,the first iteration went through successfully but the 2nd iteration fails for the same flow for which the first has gone through successfully.

Could anyone say the cause for this problem,why is it happening? I thought it would be due to the objects which are set to some value(during the first run) and not initialized to null in the second run.So when the next run happens it fails on some controls saying "Unable to find control" on some objects.But the tool recognized it successfully in the first run.If this is the problem kindly help us on the solution asap.Thanks in advance!!

regards
Amsaveni

Comment: Try to understand the problem. Try swapping the first two data rows and seeing whether the same values pass and fail. Try duplicating the first data row so there are two executions with the same test data. These and other variations should give you a view on which types of data pass and fail and whether there is something wrongly being carried from one test to another.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error if your test is running but the controls or app has not yet been loaded. Say Round 1 is finished and round 2 has begun. If you are not starting the app from a same starting point or not waiting for the control, then you will get this exception.

1. Verify that after each test has completed you app starts in the same state
2. Verify that you are waiting for your controls
3. Hand code and debug your test